# Ограничение сервиса по ресурсам в kubernetes кластере

Tags: kubernetes

Доброе время суток!

Есть сервис написанный на golang и развернут в кластере kubernetes. Kubernetes позволяет выставить ограничения по использованию ресурсов. Если на сервис выставить ограничение, заметно вырастает время ответа от сервиса.
С приложения снял trace в двух случаях, первое когда ограничения не были выставлены и второе когда были выставлены ограничения. Во втором случаи по трейсу, насколько я понял, было видно, что приложение часто ожидает процессорного времени. Хотя лимиты были заданы больше чем требуется приложению.

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема или в какую сторону копать, может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой.

Answer (score 0):

У вас есть несколько вариантов:

1. Продолжать редактировать ресурсные настройки пода(читай модуль)
2. Добавить еще один под

Вот вам небольшая [статья](https://medium.com/@betz.mark/understanding-resource-limits-in-kubernetes-memory-6b41e9a955f9) про ресурсы.

Типовые настройки пода:

```
resources:
  requests:
    cpu: 50m
    memory: 50Mi
  limits:
    cpu: 100m
    memory: 100Mi
```

Получается, что при нормальной работе этому контейнеру требуется 5 процентов процессорного времени и 50 Мбайт оперативной памяти (для выполнения запросов); максимум, на который он может расчитывать - это 10 процентов процессорного времени и 100 Мбайт оперативной памяти.